# How does Loop Quantum Gravity deal with spaghettification near a black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon, loop-quantum-gravity

How does LQG deal with spaghettification near a black hole?  Do the quantum fuzzy particles of LQG spacetime stretch out vertically as would any other quantum particle?

Comment: It is still unknown whether LQG reproduces general relativity in the classical limit. It certainly cannot be used to calculate how particles behave near a black hole event horizon. Given this, there is no answer to your question except to say that it **does not** "*deal with spaghettification near a black hole*".

Comment: @JohnRennie Thanks.  Just what I was looking for.

Comment: @JohnRennie Maybe make that comment an answer as  it will get rid of an unanswered question (from the system's point of view).